# ¿Cómo mostrar mensaje desde un select hacia iput?

Tags: javascript, php

Hola amigos cómo puedo  hacer que se envie un mensaje de "No es necesario" al darle clik en la opción "habitacion" y lo muestre en el input Direción, estoy tabajano con PHP, javascript.
Gracias.

```
$(function() {
      $("#APTO").change( function() {
         if ($(this).val() === "habitación") {
          $("#APC").prop("disabled", true);
           } else {
           $("#APC").prop("disabled", false);
         }
          });
          });

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> 
<label for="APTO">Tipo de APTO</label>
<select id="APTO" name="APTO" type="text">
   <option value="">Elija una opción</option>
   <option value="casa" >Casa</option>
   <option value="apartemento">Apartemento</option>
   <option value="habitacion">Habitación</option>
</select>
</div>

<div>
 <label  for="APC" disabled>Dirección</label>
   <input id=""APC" name="APC" type="text">
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Después de deshabilitar con `$("#APC").prop("disabled", true);` solo cambia el valor: `$("#APC").val('No es necesario');`

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un error en el if, lo correcto sería: if ($(this).val() === "habitacion")" (Habitación sin acento).

modifiqué tú código y Funcionó a la perfección:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> 
<label for="APTO">Tipo de APTO</label>
<select id="APTO" name="APTO" type="text">
   <option value="">Elija una opción</option>
   <option value="casa" >Casa</option>
   <option value="apartemento">Apartemento</option>
   <option value="habitacion">Habitación</option>
</select>
</div>

<div>
 <label  for="APC" disabled>Dirección</label>
   <input id="APC" name="APC" type="text">
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
      $("#APTO").change( function() {
         if ($(this).val() === "habitacion") {
          $("#APC").prop("disabled", true);
          $("#APC").val('No es necesario')
           } else {
           $("#APC").prop("disabled", false);
         }
          });
          });
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias Amigo!!!

Comment: De nada bro, es un placer poder ayudarle. saludos.